# Linux C++ What to do after a program ends with a still running thread?

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

If you are developing a program with threads and something went wrong..., what about the thread now, when the program ended (e.g.) with an error *and without quit the thread.
Does it need a reboot? Or quits the thread, if the process is closed? Or what?

Comment: When a process ends, all threads are killed. You can check the process status with `ps - e` command piped to grep the name of your process.

Comment: How do you reboot a thread?

Comment: You don't reboot a thread.

Comment: @MohitJain: Ish. The standard Posix implementation of `std::exit` will exit all threads (e.g. on Linux by calling the `exit_group` system call), but you can use the thread API directly to only exit the main thread and leave the others running if you really want to.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks. Is it possible with native C++ threads also?

Comment: @MohitJain: No, C++ says that when the program ends, all threads end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every thread is owned by a process. When you create threads inside your application, they are owned by the process of your application. When your application exits, either normally or after an error, the process is killed, and with him every thread that it owns.

So in a multi-threading application every thread is always automatically killed at application exit.

Comment: Thank you all. For reply, for the fast reply, for further informations!
This acceptions belonngs to all...
Greeting 
Earlybite

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding threads. Read some good [POSIX thread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) then [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html). See also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) & [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Once a Linux [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) has terminated, all its threads are gone (see [NPTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library)).

Notice that with current C++11 libraries on Linux, their `std::thread`-s are built above *pthreads*.

Answer (score 0):

When a process ends, all the threads exit too. All the resource acquired by the process will be released.